# Automapper definition by convention without explicit CreateMap

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to create Automapper conventions for mapping between DTO's with uppercase properties with underscores and business POCO's which are pascal case.

I want to do this without explicitly calling `CreateMap` for each class since the rules of mapping are same everywhere.

DTO's are prefixed with "T_".

```
// DTO 
public class T_ACCOUNT
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? PROFILE_ID { get; set; }
    public bool DELETED { get; set; }
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
    public bool IS_EMAIL_CONFIRMED { get; set; }
    public DateTime TIME { get; set; }
}

// business model
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ProfileId { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

So I create the mapper like this.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile(new DtoToBusinessProfile());
});

IMapper mapper = new Mapper(config);
```

The profile looks like this.

```
public class DtoToBusinessProfile : Profile
{
    public DtoToBusinessProfile()
    {
        // this should match mapping between "Account" and "T_ACCOUNT"
        AddConditionalObjectMapper()
            .Where((s, d) =>
            {
                return s.Name == d.Name.Substring(2).Pascalize();
            });

        // Now what?
    }
}
```

I created a [feature request](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3086) in Automapper github since [I could not get the `INamingConvention` interface to work](https://github.com/czmirek/AutomapperConventionTest/tree/master/AutomapperConventionTest/test).

I was told that what I want is also possible by using `ForAllMaps` but I have no idea what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Found [a bug](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3087) in Automapper but also a working solution with two mappers. Apparently the `LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention` works well also with uppercase properties.

```
IMapper dtoToBusinessMapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddConditionalObjectMapper()
       .Where((s, d) => s.Name == d.Name.Substring(2).Pascalize());
    cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
    cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
}).CreateMapper();

IMapper businessToDtoMapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddConditionalObjectMapper()
       .Where((s, d) => s.Name == "T_" + d.Name.Underscore().ToUpperInvariant());
    cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
    cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention(); 
}).CreateMapper();

T_ACCOUNT tableRow = new T_ACCOUNT()
{
    DELETED = 0,
    EMAIL = "asdf@asdf.cz",
    ID = 8,
    IS_EMAIL_CONFIRMED = 1,
    PROFILE_ID = 11,
    TIME = DateTime.Now
};

Account businessModel = dtoToBusinessMapper.Map<Account>(tableRow);
T_ACCOUNT backToDto = businessToDtoMapper.Map<T_ACCOUNT>(businessModel);
```